# How can I run a set of numbers through firebase DB and return match?

Tags: javascript, csv, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve unique IDs from a CSV file and find a match to the IDs in my firebase database and then copy the match to another child.

I created a CSV file contain this number format
ID 
75799757, 
9744710, 
79989647,

and this is my firebase database structure 
[image: Datab]

So far I have been able to figure out how to read a csv file with this JS code

```
      readFile = function () {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
          };
        // I assigned the IDs retrieved from the CSV file to an array named keys
          var keys = [reader.result];
          var promises = keys.map(function(key) {
              return firebase.database().ref("/Agents/").child(key).once("value");
            });
        // return the values for each ID

           Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
              snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.key+": "+snapshot.val());
              });
            });
        // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
          reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
      };
```

html file

```
  <input type="file" class="upload">
   <section class="file">
  </section>
```

css file

```
body {
padding: 3em;
}

.file {
border: solid 1px gray;
padding: 25px;
margin: 25px;
}
```

the file firebase call is not working, I was able to retrieve the IDs from the CSV file but I could not get it find the matching IDs and console log their values. What am I doing wrong? how can I fix this so that it will return the firebase values matching the IDs in the array?

Comment: There are quite a few steps involved in this. Answering all of them essentially leads to somebody building an entire app for you, which is too broad to do on Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you tell us what exact step you're stuck at. Are you having trouble reading the CSV with the code you have? Is it reading, but are you having a hard time parsing the CSV? Is it a problem in calling Firebase? Single out the thing you're stuck at and then [create the minimal code that reproduces only that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edit the code and question. I just want to obtain the firebase values for each respective ID from the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that could be wrong. But the first thing that jumps out is that you have the code that uses the CSV, outside of the `onload()` callback. That seems like a mistake.

```
  readFile = function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;

        // I assigned the IDs retrieved from the CSV file to an array named keys
        var keys = [reader.result];
        var promises = keys.map(function(key) {
            return firebase.database().ref("/Agents/").child(key).once("value");
        });
        // read the data from the database for each ID
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
          snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.key+": "+snapshot.val());
          });
        });
      };

      // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
  };
```

Comment: it still not calling to firebase and I'm not getting any error from the console.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient tool for remotely debugging your app. For example, I have no idea if your CSV is being parsed correctly. *You* can step through the code in a debugger, but with the information you've provided I can't easily do that. There are likely more problems in your code, but this was definitely one of the mistakes.